# Python запись массива в Excel

Tags: python, excel

Всем привет , вообщем мне нужно постранично записывать данные в Excel из списка (1 проблема не записывается).Вот собственна проблема , тут так же видно что данные записываются только те которые явно указаны и может кто сможет мне указать на проблему связанную с этим.

```
File "C:/Users/igor/Desktop/4Wscript/test.py", line 123, in export_excel
    worksheet.write(row, col, data[field])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
{'index': ['69039'], 'name': '', 'group': 'Люстри', 'description': '', 'maker': '', 'country': 'Чехія', 'design': 'класичний', 'lamp': '', 'socle': '', 'color_lamp': '', 'type_lamp': '', 'color_stl': '', 'type_stl': '', 'heightm': '', 'width': '', 'depth': ''}
1
index
0
index
```

Вообщем задача такая , записывать данные в Excel , а поскольку запись постраничная , в Excel будет записываться по одной строке , после записи первой строки должна проходить проверка на заполнение поля по типу если в поле есть значение , спускаемся на следующую строку и вставляем туда данные. Может кто подскажет какими средствами можно это сделать , ибо с xlsxwriter чёт не пошло.

PS:проверка не написана ибо сама запись не работатет

```
def get_html(url):
    html = requests.get(url)
    return html


def get_page_data(html):
    tf = ''
    lamp = tf
    socle = tf
    group = 'Люстри'
    country = 'Чехія'
    design = 'класичний'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text)
    info = soup.find('div', class_='catalog_hr')#.find_all('b')[5].text

    tovname = soup.find('div', class_='catalog_tovname').find('a').text
    index = re.findall('(\d+)',tovname )
        try:
             heightm = ad.find('b')[2].text
        except:
            heightm = ''
        try:
            width = ad.find('b')[3].text
        except:
            width = ''
        try:
            in_lamp = ad.find('b')[4]
            lamp = in_lamp.split('x')[0]
            socle = in_lamp.split('x')[1]
        except:
            in_lamp = ''
        try:
            color_stl = ad.find('b')[7].text
        except:
            color_stl = ''
        try:
            type_stl = ad.find('b')[8].text
        except:
            type_stl = ''
        try:
            color_lamp = ad.find('b')[9].text
        except:
            color_lamp = ''
        try:
            type_lamp = ad.find('b')[10].text
        except:
            type_lamp = ''
        try:
            maker = ad.find('b')[12].text
        except:
            maker = ''

        data = {'index': index,
                    'name': tf,
                    'group': group,
                    'description': tf,
                    'maker': maker,
                    'country': country,
                    'design': design,
                    'lamp': lamp,
                    'socle': socle,
                    'color_lamp': color_lamp,
                    'type_lamp': type_lamp,
                    'color_stl': color_stl,
                    'type_stl': type_stl,
                    'heightm': heightm,
                    'width': width,
                    'depth': heightm}
    return data


def export_excel(filename , datas):
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(filename)
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    field_names = ('код товару',
                     'назва серії, модель',
                      'група товару для сайту',
                      'опис',
                      'виробник',
                      'країна',
                      'дизайн',
                      'кількість патронів',
                      'цоколь',
                      'колір плафона',
                      'матеріал плафона',
                      'колір арматури',
                      'матеріал арматури',
                      'розмір (см) Ш',
                      'розмір (см) В',
                      'розмір (см) Г',
                      'фото')

    for i ,field in enumerate(field_names):
        worksheet.write(0, i, field)

    fields = ('index', 'name', 'group',
     'description', 'maker','country', 
     'design', 'lamp', 'socle', 'color_lamp',
     'type_lamp','color_stl','type_stl',
     'heightm','width','depth')
    for row, data in enumerate(datas, start=1):
        print(row)
        print(data)
        for col, field in enumerate(fields):
            print(col)
            print(field)
            worksheet.write(row, col, data[field])

    workbook.close()

def main():
    url = 'https://www.lampa.kiev.ua/ua/katalog/searchANJA+X'
    html = get_html(url)
    datas = get_page_data(html)
    print(datas)
    export_excel('data.xlsx', datas)
```

[image: Вывод программы]

Comment: Вы можете привести несколько строк из того, что вы хотите получить на выходе - для примера?

Comment: В Excel?  Кстати принты в цикле фор к проге не относятся я просто их написал что бы видеть на каком они этапе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё расходимся ребят , вот ответ:
проблема была тут

```
index = re.findall('(\d+)',tovname )
```

метод findall превращал int  в list[]
я этого не знал.
решение:

```
index = re.findall('(\d+)',tovname )[0]
```

или (мне подсказали)

```
index = re.search(r'\d+', tovname).group()
```